# Updating my app to playstore, the new version is inactive, what can i do?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, post, apk, account

The new version remain in Appbundle as you can see it in my Screenshot
[screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Asqse.png)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to submit it to review to Playstore go to your `Production` in release and send it fro review from there.